# How to avoid getting Nan while adding entries of two different csv columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, histogram

I am adding two different csv columns to make 2D hist plot. I have two different types of data which are `dense` and `collision`.

Further, each data includes information of my case study with column `type` where I have `type=0` (big) and `type=1`(small).
csv looks like this(from collision):

```
TIMESTEP id     type    a      |f|     |v|  
20000   4737     0     9.81  1.31495  4.18007   
40000  11991     1     9.81  4.43794  4.17909   
50000  15725     1     9.81  4.43794  4.17810     
30000   8209     0     9.81  4.43794  4.17810     
15000   3545     0     9.81  1.31495  4.17810   
30000   8269     0     9.81  4.43794  4.17810    
10000   2077     1     9.81  1.31495  4.17712   
20000   5079     0     9.81  1.31495  4.17712
```

All data are `float` types with positive entries.

When I plot `a` and `|f|` from both  types for `type=0` (big) and `type=1`(small) separetely I don't have any problem. Also plot makes sense. However, plotting `a` and `|f|` from `small + big` (i.e sum of each entry from each part) looks weird.

I realized `small + big` gave me almost `90%` Nan though original data doesn't have any `Nan`.

How can I avoid `Nan` while doing `small + big` to make a perfect hist plot?

I realized data is missing in `collision:Small+Big`. I was expecting to have plot like `Dense:Small+Big`.

My code is here:

```
from cProfile import label
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

df_collision_big = df_collision[df_collision['type'] == 0]
df_collision_small = df_collision[df_collision['type'] == 1]

df_dense_big =   df_dense[df_dense['type'] == 0]
df_dense_small = df_dense[df_dense['type'] == 1]


plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))
#make space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.6)
plt.subplot(231)
plt.hist2d(df_collision_small['a'], df_collision_small['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Collision: Small')
plt.subplot(232)
plt.hist2d(df_collision_big['a'], df_collision_big['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Collision: Big')
plt.subplot(233)
plt.hist2d(df_collision_big['a'] + df_collision_small['a'], df_collision_big['|f|'] + df_collision_small['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Collision: Small + Big')

plt.subplot(234)
plt.hist2d(df_dense_small['a'], df_dense_small['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Dense: Small')
plt.subplot(235)
plt.hist2d(df_dense_big['a'], df_dense_big['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Dense: Big')
plt.subplot(236)
plt.hist2d(df_dense_big['a'] + df_dense_small['a'], df_dense_big['|f|'] + df_dense_small['|f|'], bins=np.linspace(0,70,15), norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('|f|')
plt.title('Dense: Big + Small')
plt.savefig('hist2d.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Printing `df_collision['a]` gives me this:

```
175761    9.810009
409899    9.810058
429591    9.810058
358086    9.810009
89079     9.810009
            ...   
243866    9.810058
125778    9.810009
185374    9.810009
496586    9.810058
234942    9.810058
Name: a, Length: 27832, dtype: float64
```

Most of the values in `a` are similar.

printing `df_collision_big['a'] + df_collision_small['a']` gives me this:

```
0         19.620067
1         19.620067
2         19.620067
3         19.620067
4         19.620067
            ...    
504208          NaN
504209          NaN
504210          NaN
504211          NaN
504212          NaN
Name: a, Length: 18639, dtype: float64
```

One more thing:

printing len of small and big gives me this:

```
print(len(df_collision_small['a']))
print(len(df_collision_big['a']))

# Output
13772
14060
```

Hoping for some suggestions to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This is happening due to imbalance of count of rows in the two dataframes. When you sum two columns from two dataframes, they are merely added by indices. Is that what you want? How do you relate the records from two dataframes? Eg by some common column value (like in SQL join) or just the position (index) of the records.

Comment: Thank you Azhar for your reply. Yes, I want to add them with position. Since, data is mixed with type one and type two. I would like to separete them first. After that I want to add them like first row of type 1 and first row of type 2, 2nd row of type 1 and 2nd row of type 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the `NaN` issue in summation as:

```py
pd.merge(df_collision_small["a"], df_dense_big["a"], how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True).sum(axis=1)
```

**Explanation**

`outer join` on index results in a dataframe with "a" from both dataframes put together (index/position wise):

```py
df_collision_small = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2]})
>>    a
>> 0  1
>> 1  2

df_dense_big = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [10,20,30,40]})
>>     a
>> 0  10
>> 1  20
>> 2  30
>> 3  40

pd.merge(df_collision_small, df_dense_big, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>    a_x  a_y
>> 0  1.0   10
>> 1  2.0   20
>> 2  NaN   30
>> 3  NaN   40
```

`sum(axis=1)` ignores `NaN` while summing values:

```py
pd.merge(df_collision_small["a"], df_dense_big["a"], how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True).sum(axis=1)
>> 0    11.0
>> 1    22.0
>> 2    30.0
>> 3    40.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this and will come back here.